# Postman pre-request-script URL not defined

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I have a pre-request-script in Postman which need to create URL:

```
var uri = new URL(request.url).pathname;
console.log("uri:" + uri);
```

Which failed with error: URL is not defined. I searched around and tried all different ways:

```
//const url = require('url');
//const URL = require('url').URL;
```

None of them work. I check node version and npm, it showed those are on installed

```
node -v
-bash: node: command not found
npm -v
-bash: npm: command not found
```

Do I have to install node for this to work?

I also run the code in chrome developer tool console, same result as undefined:

```
var uri = new URL(request.url).pathname
undefined
```

But in the same script I also use CryptoJS, which doesn't require any import, it just works.

I'm using macOS Mojave 10.14.6, and POSTMAN 7.21.2 app, not chrome extension.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve, maybe someone can offer a different solution? You can use `pm.request.url = "My URL"` in the pre-request scripts.

Comment: i need to get the path from the url, updated my post: new URL(request.url).pathname

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postman has support for APIs, some of them are pre-included. CryptoJS, for example, is pre-included, hence you'd not need to add explicitly. The pre-request script has also support for several node modules, to make them work, Postman documentation stated:

> In order to use a library, simply call the require function and pass
>   the module name as a parameter and assign the return of the function
>   to a variable.

So, in your case, it should be something like:

```
const url = require('url');
var pathName = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

console.log(pathName);
```

Detailed documentation: [Postman Sandbox API reference](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox-api-reference/)

Comment: It's a little bit inconsistent to be honest, as some don't actually need the require statement to bring them in to the sandbox. Lodash being an example of this - Using `_.*` function would work out of the box. 

Comment: @DannyDainton Ah okay, wasn't aware of that.